# MVC4 Entity Framework - Set Field value before Insertion/Update

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with an MVC 4 ASP.NET website using Entity Framework. This is my first ASP.NET website and sorry if I don't make much sense.

The website hosts posts, just think of an WordPress like blog. I expect to have a title property and a slug property which is implicitly derived from the title. So this is the class for the 'Post'.

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual int PostID { get; set; }

    public virtual String Title { get; set; }

    public virtual string Slug { get; set; }

}
```

How could I set 'Slug' when inserting/updating the entry. I assume I have to tap in to the method that updates/inserts the database. It seems to be hiding. I am wondering if annotations could do the trick.

Apart from that and auto generated forms, I have a `DbContext`extended class with the `OnModelCreating` implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that code, the Slug property isn't being derived from anything. If you want it to be derived from the title, you could try something like this:

```
private string title;
public virtual string Title {
    get { return title; }
    set {
        title = value;
        Slug = title.replace(" ", "-");
    }
}

public virtual string Slug { get; private set; }
```

Comment: That should work and it is simple... thanks... with another if statement it should work. I actually trimmed down the class as other info are irrelevant... I will check and let u know!